# Web Hosting using own domain (Weebly)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-hosting

I have finished building a new website using HTML, CSS, JS, and Bootstrap for a non profit organization as volunteer and currently they are using Weebly to host their site. I have simply been using my student domain hosted by my college to show my progress of the website, but now that I have finished I want to transfer it over to their official site. I was wondering if it is even possible to transfer all my code into Weebly and not use their pre-made themes? Especially since I am using Bootstrap. Will I have to tell them they need a new web hosting service if they want to use the website I designed them? Cause I am having trouble with Weebly doing that.

Sorry if this a dumb question, I am not knowledgeable about Web hosting and recently begun designing websites.
Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like you can upload your custom code. You have to make the site using their own site builder on weebly. You will have to find a new host for your website. Source: http://kb.weebly.com/ftp-access.html

Answer (score 0):

You could advise the organization to switch web hosting providers. There are many out there that are free or provide discounts for non-profits. Deploy your website there, then get their existing domain provider to redirect theirdomain.com to the new provider.

Answer (score 0):

Is that non-profit organisation using free website from weebly ? i mean subdomain ? e.g. xyz.weebly.com ?

If yes, in free acoount of weebly, there are many restrictions on features...

Till u can use your own codes in weebly...
(weebly does not support php)

Log in to weebly and follow images attached below to go to edit weebly html/css

[image]

[image]

[image]